# RxJS and AngularJS HTTP - how can I achieve this?

Tags: http, angular, observable, rxjs

I'm writing a small utility function that wrap a call to AngularJS http.get with the necessary authentication headers:

```
get(endpoint: string): Observable {
    var headers = new Headers();
    this._appendAuthentificationHeaders( headers, this.user.credentials);

    return this.http.get(endpoint, { headers: headers })
            .map(res => res.json());
}
```

The point here is that if **this.user** is null, the method will just crash.
So I have three options:

1. Return null and check that return value on every call...
2. Throw an exception
3. Find a way to also return an RxJS Observable object that will directly trigger the error handler.

I would like to implement the third method, as it would allow me unify this method's behavior: It always returns an observable no matter what happen.

- Do you have an idea about how to do that?
- Do I have to create a new Observable and kind of merge those two?
- What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `user` is `null`, you can simply return a raw observable that triggers an error:

```
if (this.user == null) {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    observer.error('User is null');
  });
}

(...)
```

or leverage the `throw` operator:

```
if (this.user == null) {
  return Observable.throw('User is null');
}

(...)
```

This way the second method of the `subscribe` method will be called:

```
observable.subscribe(
  (data) => {
    (...)
  },
  (err) => {
    // Will be called in this case
  }
);
```

Comment: i'l go for Observable.throw('User is null');

Thanks a lot !

Comment: A manual `Observable.throw()` has proven to be one of the most underused and most useful error handling patterns I've encountered in Rx/angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way would be to wrap the whole function body to an observable, as it will turn any accidental error to an observable error. Something like this:

```
get(endpoint: string): Observable {
  return Rx.Observable.defer(() => {
    var headers = new Headers();
    this._appendAuthentificationHeaders(headers, this.user.credentials);
    return Rx.Observable.just(headers);
  })
  .flatMap(headers => this.http.get(endpoint, { headers: headers }))
  .map(res => res.json());
}
```

However I still do not agree with `http.get` returning an observable instead of a promise. As these are single valued observables, your function could be a simple async function (sry, js instead of ts):

```
async get(endpoint) {
  var headers = new Headers();
  this._appendAuthentificationHeaders(headers, this.user.credentials);
  const res = await this.http.get(endpoint, { headers })).toPromise();
  return res.json();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
In my opinion, Observable are a superset of promises, so let's use only one consistent api.

Comment: @Clement The big difference which makes Promises and Observables somewhat different is that Observables are replayable. Keep this in mind when you try to implement some caching mechanism with observables :) But yeah, observables are the superset of promises. I guess we will have to adapt async-await to observables as well.

Comment: What do you mean by replayable ?

Comment: Well, right, replayable is not the correct term. Observables are either hot or cold (when I said replayable I thought about cold ones). The angular2 api docs doesn't say if http.get is hot or cold. If it's hot, then late subscribers might miss the result value, if it's cold, every subscription will trigger a new http request.